# What code reads /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, lxc

Some time back `ifconfig`, `ifup` and friends got replaced. Generally `/etc/network/interfaces` seems to work in Ubuntu.

I'm running an LXC container which does not have `ifup`

my `/etc/network/interfaces` is

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.3.26
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.3.0
```

If I run the new

```
ip link set dev eth0 up
```

I get an IP assigned by DHCP

```
ip a

15: eth0@if16: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc 
noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:84:8f:8d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.0.3.190/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global dynamic eth0
```

N.B "dynamic eth0"

If `/etc/network/interfaces` is no longer used what is its replacement?

Comment: Are you sure that your gateway of `10.0.3.0` is correct?  Because with `255.255.255.0` networks, the IP address that ends in `.0` is usually for the network.  Shouldn't it be `10.0.3.1` for the gateway?

Comment: which release of ubuntu you are using?